# XSLT for removing tags from a XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<results>
  <output>
    <status>OK</status>
    <usage>Please use it</usage>
    <url/>
    <language>english</language>
    <category>science_technology</category>
    <score>0.838661</score>
  </output>
</results>
```

I want to remove the tags `<output> </output>` from this XML.

OUTPUT EXPECTED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <results>
 <status>OK</status>
    <usage>Please use it</usage>
    <url/>
    <language>english</language>
    <category>science_technology</category>
    <score>0.838661</score>

</results>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Show the exact output you want, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- the overriding of the identity rule.

Comment: Can there be multiple `<output>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortest as possible:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="results">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="output/*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or using identity rule:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="results">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="output/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4):

**The easiest way to do this** (almost mechanically and without thinking):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="output"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<results>
  <output>
    <status>OK</status>
    <usage>Please use it</usage>
    <url/>
    <language>english</language>
    <category>science_technology</category>
    <score>0.838661</score>
  </output>
</results>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<results>
   <status>OK</status>
   <usage>Please use it</usage>
   <url/>
   <language>english</language>
   <category>science_technology</category>
   <score>0.838661</score>
</results>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule/template copies every node "as is**".
2. **There is a single template overriding the identity rule**. It matches any `output` element and prevents it from being copied to the output, but continues the processing of any of its children.

**Remember**: Overriding the identity rule is the most fundamental and most powerful XSLT design pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It worked .I want to learn more about XLST. Is there any link which I can refer to understand it as I have various XML files from which I need to fetch the data..

Comment: @aniket69: The established way of expressing gratitude here at SO is to accept the best answer -- by clicking at the check-mark next to it. I am glad my answer was useful. And yes, XSLT is beautiful, powerful and elegant. See this for links to books and tutorials: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589